# conformal mapping from $\left|\arg z\right| < α < π$ onto the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Find a holomorphic function $\ w = f(z)$ mapping the sector $\left|\arg z\right| < α < π$
conformally onto the unit circle $\ |w| < 1$. Describe the behavior of $\ f (z)$ near $\ z = 0$.

I know how to map the upper plane to the unit circle, but have no idea about a sector, I am thinking about first map this to the upper plane... shall I take log?

Comment: $\log$ will map to $\mathbb{R} \times (-\alpha, \alpha)$.

Comment: How $z^n$ works?

Comment: It's not the unit circle, it's the open unit disc.

Answer (score 5):

First do the map $z \rightarrow z^{ \frac{ \pi}{2 \alpha}}$ to send it to the positive real half plane.

[image]
Then the map 
\begin{eqnarray*}
z \rightarrow \frac{z-1}{z+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
will map this to the unit circle.

Comment: If we want to find a conformal map from $\{|\arg{z}|<\alpha<\pi, |z|\leq 1\}$ to the unit circle couldn't we apply immediately $z^{2\pi/2\alpha}$? So that we unwrap the sector not only to the half plane but to the entire plane?